# Selecting 2 tables in the same editor

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

In SQL I can write 2 separate SELECT statements and execute them at the same time, such as:

SELECT * FROM Table_Name

SELECT * FROM Another_Table

Is it possible to do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: This has nothing to do with "PostgreSQL" but all with the SQL client you are using.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're really asking a PGAdmin question. In SQL Server's query analyzer / Enterprise Manager if you execute two select statements, two result sets will be displayed in the output area.

PGAdmin doesn't do this; you need two separate query windows to see both result sets. I know of no other free GUI admin tool for PostgreSQL. Maybe someone else will.

EDIT:
I've recently started using Squirrel-SQL and DBeaver. Either of these may be more what you're looking for. I prefer DBeaver myself.

Brian